# MySQL LEFT JOIN two nested tables performance

Tags: mysql, performance, nested

I have query similar to this, this code works, but have performance issues:

```
SELECT Mat.Name, Inc.Quantity, Outg.Quantity FROM Materials AS Mat
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MaterialsID, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM Incoming GROUP BY MaterialsID ) AS Inc
ON Inc.MaterialsID=Mat.ID
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MaterialsID, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity FROM Outgoing GROUP BY MaterialsID ) AS Outg
ON Outg.MaterialsID=Mat.ID
ORDER BY Mat.ID ASC
LIMIT 10
```

No matter if LIMIT (or WHERE clause) selects 1, 10 or 1000 rows, execution time is the same (which in my case is 4 seconds if not cached).
Is there good approach to optimize this query while keeping code readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appears to be happening is that you have a pair of sub queries (which are possibly not quick), and then the results are joined against the Materials table before discarding all except the first 10 ids. If there are a large number of records on materials then this is doing a large and slow join (a sub query is not going to pass back an index to be used in the join) before dropping most of the records

While I am normally not keen on them, this is probably a time when you would need to use a sub query in the SELECT( a correlated sub query). This will mean it will only calculate the quantities for the 10 records you care about.

```
SELECT Mat.Name, 
        ( SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM Incoming WHERE MaterialsID=Mat.ID ) Inc_Quantity, 
        ( SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM Outgoing WHERE MaterialsID=Mat.ID ) Out_Quantity
FROM Materials AS Mat
ORDER BY Mat.ID ASC
```

LIMIT 10

Comment: Great answer, i am glad i asked that question.

Comment: Only problem i already found out, is that i can forget about to try sort by those fields. This, most likely, cannot be solved by just optimizing query.

Comment: Doing this, no you cannot sort against those fields efficiently. But if you want to sort against one of them you can put that one in the main query (and assuming you are not interested in ones with a NULL sum then you can just use an INNER JOIN  without a sub query) and use the correlated sub query for the 2nd one (the one you are not sorting on).

Comment: I suppose, indexing tables Incoming and Outgoing by field MaterialsID will also greatly add to performance?   I am not very familiar wit indexing right now, so i will leave this as resort to use when database grows further.

Comment: Yes that would greatly help the sub queries (sorry, I assumed you already had such indexes), but these indexes won't be carried through from the sub queries to the outer SELECT in your original query.